# Change the theme of Recaptcha?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

I use the Following script for change recaptcha in asp.net with c# server side.But this code Didn't Work.**How to change color or theme of the ReCaptcha?**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = {theme : 'White'};
       </script>
```

Comment: The theme name is 'white' not 'White' note the capital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just writing the name of the theme in wrong way, just try White with a small 'w'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = {theme : 'white'};
</script>
```

See this link for exact working code:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

Answer (score 2):

George Siggouroglou's second method for asp.net is a charm

I couldn't seem to set the theme as instructed in https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization - placed the js above the form containing the recaptcha control - but adding the theme attribute directly into the recaptcha code as George explained:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
    ID="recaptcha"
    runat="server"
    PublicKey="your-public-key"
    PrivateKey="your-private-key"
    Theme="white"
/>
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

U used the capital `W` instead of small i.e. `w`
Try this

Change the theme and try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'white'
    /*WE CAN USE FOLLOWING THEME TO CHANGE THE COLOR OF RECAPTHCA*/
    /*red,white,blackglass,clean'*/

    /*lang :'es';*/ //used to set the language
 };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net and if you are using the [recapctcha for asp.net control](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet), then if you want to change the theme (red(default),white,blackglass,clean) there is two ways.

[Way no1,](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization)

> To make the reCAPTCHA widget display a different theme, you first need to add the following
>   code in your main HTML page anywhere **before** the  element where reCAPTCHA appears
>   (this will not work if placed after the main script where reCAPTCHA is first invoked):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'theme_name'
    };
</script>
```

Way no2:

> Add the property 'Theme' to the recapcha asp.net control:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
    ID="recaptcha"
    runat="server"
    PublicKey="your-public-key"
    PrivateKey="your-private-key"
    Theme="white"
/>
```